# Dom Traversing the Dom with JavaScript but event not hitting the Html Element

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I want to add delete functionality to a button on an Li element that is dynamically created by Javascript but I can't seem to be able to get the event listener to hit the target button.

I tried adding it right away by doing

```
    var trashButton = document.getElementsByClassName("deleteListItemButton");
    trashButton.addEventListener('click',removeLiItem);
```

but I got an unhandled exception error

```
var idForLiElement =1;

document.getElementById("addTaskId").addEventListener('click', function(){

var valueFromTextBox = document.getElementById("textBoxId").value; 

if(valueFromTextBox) addItemToDo(valueFromTextBox);
});

function addItemToDo(valueFromTextBox){

var unorderedList = document.getElementById("toDoId")

var listElement =  document.createElement("li");
listElement.className ="listItem";
listElement.innerHTML = valueFromTextBox;
listElement.id =Number(idForLiElement);
idForLiElement ++;

//puts the newest list element before the last element
unorderedList.insertBefore(listElement, unorderedList.childNodes[0]);

//creates the  div that will contain both buttons in each list element
var buttonsContainer =  document.createElement("div");
buttonsContainer.className ="listItemButtonContainer";

//creates the delete button and assigns it a class name
var deleteButton =  document.createElement("Button")
deleteButton.className ="deleteListItemButton";

//creates the complete button and assigns it a class name
var completeButton =  document.createElement("Button")
completeButton.className ="completeListItemButton";

//creates the delete image tag and assigns it a class name
var trashImageTag =  document.createElement("i")
trashImageTag.className = "fa fa-trash fa-2x";

//creates the check mark button and assigns it a class name
var checkMarkImageTag =  document.createElement("i")
checkMarkImageTag.className= "fa fa-check fa-2x";

//appends delete image tag to delete button
deleteButton.appendChild(trashImageTag);

//appends check mark image tag to complete button
completeButton.appendChild(checkMarkImageTag);

//appends delete button to button container
buttonsContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);

//appends complete button to button container
buttonsContainer.appendChild(completeButton)

//appends button container to list element
listElement.appendChild(buttonsContainer);
};

var trashButton = document.getElementsByClassName("deleteListItemButton");

for (i = 0; i < trashButton.length; i++) {
trashButton[i].addEventListener('click',removeLiItem)
};

function removeLiItem(e){
console.log(this)
};
```

I just want the event listener to hit console.log so I know the button is working

Comment: You don't need to search the DOM for the item since you are creating it in the same function.

Answer (score 1):

Attach the event to the element you've just created

```
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() { console.log('hit!') })
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add delete functionality to a button on an Li element that is dynamically created by javascript but I cant seem to be able to get the event listener to hit the target button.

The elements are dynamically created, so by the time the elements are created, the `for` loop where you add the event listeners has already executed.

This is what [event propogation](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) is for. Let the parent element (`ul`) listen to event clicks instead of having each child hold the responsibility. That way it doesnt matter how many children elements are added, momma (parent element) will always be listening for clicks.

You can do something like this:

```
// on your ul element
const itemList = document.querySelector(".item-list");

// listen for click on here
itemList.addEventListener('click', removeLiItem);

// you can access the actual element through the event's `target`
function removeLiItem (event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('deleteListItemButton') {
    // remove element
  }
}
```